# Window property databinding not updating when INotifyPropertyChanged sent, but child element properties are

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I have a window whose properties and child element properties bind to a class called `Data`:

```
public TerminalOverlay(Data dataContext)
{
    DataInstance = dataContext;
    DataContext = DataInstance;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The window `TerminalOverlay` is created in my `MainWindow` window, as follows:

```
public void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _terminalOverlayWindow = new TerminalOverlay(_dataInstance);
    _terminalOverlayWindow.Owner = this;
    _terminalOverlayWindow.Show();
}
```

`_dataInstance` is instantiated in the constructor of MainWindow, and one of the "problem" properties in it is the following:

```
public double ? PosX
{
    get
    {
        return _posX == null ? _defaultPosX : _posX;
    }
    set
    {
        _posX = value;

        OnPropertyChanged("PosX");
    }
}
```

Where OnPropertyChanged is implemented as follows:
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

The `Data` object is passed from the main window which creates `TerminalOverlay`. The Data object also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so when I update properties in the Data object from the main window, they are reflected in the `TerminalOverlay` window.

However, this is only the case for the child elements of the `TerminalOverlay` window. The properties of the `TerminalOverlay` window itself are initially set to the values stored in the Data class, but they do not seem to update, even though the child elements do.

What am I doing wrong? Looking in the visual tree I found that `TerminalOverlay.DataContext.TopX` did update, it's just that the window isn't being notified to update.

Also, TerminalOverlay.xaml looks like the following:

```
<Window x:Class="Background_Terminal.TerminalOverlay"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Background_Terminal"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TerminalOverlay" Height="200" Width="800" Left="{Binding PosX, Mode=OneWay}" Top="{Binding PosY, Mode=OneWay}" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="Transparent" Loaded="TerminalOverlay_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TerminalData_TextBox" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Consolas" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" Text="{Binding TerminalDataDisplay, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Input_TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The properties like `FontSize` in `Input_TextBox` update properly, but `Top` and `Left` in the Window properties do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your posX is a Nullable variable : they have "special" binding art

try this here

`Left="{Binding PosX, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Note that the initial value of PosX in the Data class does successfully determine the initial TerminalOverlay Left position, it's just that the window doesn't update upon OnPropertyChanged being called.

Comment: @ShaneDuffy it's curious, is there any public repo of your code so i could try it?

Comment: Awww that did it! Thanks man. Why did that work though? Did something else set the Left property of window and break the binding?

Comment: @ShaneDuffy to be honest idk either and this [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89e77097-7553-4cbb-b17c-f0784a4fd1b1/why-doesnt-a-windows-bound-top-property-change-the-windows-position?forum=wpf] guys here do not really too :(

Comment: Because the idea of the program is that the position of the window shouldn't be able to be altered anyway except via that databinding, so I'd naturally set it to be a oneway binding.

Comment: @ShaneDuffy there is some speculation in that link, but idk if that is the reason why it is not working with OneWay :(